# Spring Boot : REST API Endpoint to start & stop SSL enabled KAFKA Consumer : asking for authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

I have the following REST API Endpoint to start & stop SSL enabled KAFKA Consumer however it is asking for authentication.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/kafka/consumer")
public class KafkaConsumerStartStopController {
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
    /**
     * start Kafka.
     */
    @GetMapping("/start")
    public String start() {
        kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start();
        return "started listening";
    }
    /**
     * stop kafka.
     */
    @GetMapping("/stop")
    public String stop() {
        kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop();
        return "stopped listening";
    }
}
```

> {"timestamp":"2021-03-23T19:53:52.712+00:00","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"","path":"/kafka/consumer/start"}

[image]

I have already configured the SASL properties along with the username, password & trust.jks in the application profile.

How do I get my REST API authenticated and start/stop the kafka consumer?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Kafka; it is Spring Web Security.

See the Spring Boot documentation regarding web security.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.4/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-security

Comment: How do I disable the authentication for the entire applications, if not at least for this REST API controller? I could access the actuator/health endpoint without any authentication issue.

Comment: Read the documentation I pointed you to; it explains how to disable web security.